# How to run script after jQuery.getScript is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a use case where I am checking if code is on the page, if it is not I use `$.getScript` to fetch the script. In the done I am trying to call a function that is in that script but it gives an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: listInit is not defined`. I have also set an interval to check for the function, but it is not finding it. What would be a good way to call the function that is in the external I am calling in? Here is the get script call, and my function that is in my external:

Get Script:

```
jQuery.getScript(scriptUrl)
      .done(function() {
        listInit(listOptions);
      });
```

Function in external that is called in:

```
var listInit = function(options) {
    console.log(options)
}
```

I can see in the network tab the call and the response shows my minified code. I have also tried this to see if the function is available:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var findListFunction = setInterval(function(){
    if (typeof listInit !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(listInit)) {
      console.log('Its available')
    }else{
      console.log('no such function')
    }
  },1000);
});
```

EDIT:

I put a console log in the external file outside of the function. The console log is executed once the external is called in. I just cant seem to get the function to run.

Comment: You are calling `listInit`, but the error is telling you that `listModal` is not defined. is this a typo or what ? Is there something in the `options` that might cause the error?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Really is listInit

Comment: first add a .fail and console.log that

Comment: @user3791775 I did try. It console logs the done, not the .fail. I can also see the minified code in the response on the network tab

Comment: I also added a console log in the external outside the function that is executed when the getScript is called. I just cant seem to get the function in the external to run

Comment: Does it work if you do `window.listInit = function() {`? Maybe you're in a function scope

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think you are right here. The external when compiled is wrapped in a self executing function. I just thought about this today and realized this is why it wont call it. I will have to assign the variable to window for it to work as in your solution above.